# Add a counter to jquery isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using [isotope jquery plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) on a project and I'd like to display a simple counter on each item giving the position of the item itself after re-ordering.

What I mean is the item which display first should display '1' value, the third '3', and so on.

It seems to be very simple, but since now, I'm not able to do that.

I even try to call a callback function (triggered when completed) with the following code :

```
$cont.isotope({
                    sortBy: $(this).attr('data-filter'),
                     sortAscending: eval($(this).attr('data-sort'))
            }, onAnimationFinished );

var onAnimationFinished = function(){

  var cnt = 0;
  $(".feature").each(function (index) {
        cnt++;
        console.log("counter : " + parseInt(cnt));
        $(this).find('div.counter-container > span.legend').append(' ' + parseInt(cnt));
   });

};
```

But this has no effect. The display value is still the initial value. Any idea would be welcome. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Question was answered by David DeSandro on github repository : https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/545#issuecomment-25571902

> Currently, if you want to get the order of items, you can do so by accessing the $filteredAtoms property. See http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#accessing_the_instance

Thanks to him. It works well with that. Hope it helps others.